# How to patch core via drush-make when using a stub make file?

Tags: drush

When using a stub make file based profile workflow as suggested in [Drush Make theory for happy profile development](https://www.drupal.org/node/1006620) I notice that patches to core are no longer applied.

I've tested this by reverting to a single make file workflow - core patches get applied just fine that way.

Has anyone else found a fix/workaround for this?

---

UPDATE with details...

---

Here's what my stub make file looks like:

```
api = 2
core = 7.x

projects[] = drupal

projects[example_profile][download][type] = "git"
projects[example_profile][download][url] = "git@github.com:danohea/example-profile.git"
projects[example_profile][type] = "profile"
```

Which as you can see is designed to go grab a custom profile. I should mention that that is not the real path to the profile (which is a private repo anyway).

The profile contains a further make file that looks a bit like this (shortened for convenience):

```
api = 2
core = 7.x

; Contrib modules (not in dev)

; Specify common subdir of "contrib"
defaults[projects][subdir] = "contrib"

projects[admin_menu][version] = 3
projects[ctools][version] = 1
projects[diff][version] = 3
projects[eck][version] = 2
projects[entity][version] = 1
projects[jquery_update][version] = 3
projects[libraries][version] = 2
projects[link][version] = 1
projects[module_filter][version] = 2
projects[pathauto][version] = 1
projects[token][version] = 1
projects[transliteration][version] = 3
projects[views][version] = 3

; Contrib modules (in dev)

projects[wysiwyg][version] = 2.x-dev
; Keep in dev until this issue makes it to stable:
; https://drupal.org/node/1956778

; Themes

projects[omega][version] = 4
projects[omega][subdir] = "contrib"

; Libraries

; ckeditor
libraries[ckeditor][download][type] = file
libraries[ckeditor][download][url] = http://ckeditor.com/builder/download/a63002d0b001ab7841c8e29bb8081e57 

; Patches

; drupal
; Ignore front end vendor folders to improve directory search performance
projects[drupal][patch][2329453] = https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/optimize_scan-2329453-84-do-not-test.patch

; pathauto
; Merge in pathauto_persist module functionality to prevent losing manual aliases with node_save() calls
projects[pathauto][patch][936222] = https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/merge_in-936222-299.patch
```

The stub make file is run with a command that looks a bit like this:

```
drush make --prepare-install path/to/stub.make -y
```

I'm running Drush version 7.0.0.

Note that there are 2 patches, one for drupal core and one for pathauto. The pathauto one is applied as expected, the drupal one doesn't seem to even run.

If I download & run the profile's make file directly (i.e. not via the stub) then the core patch is applied as expected.

If I move the drupal core patch to the stub make file, it still doesn't run.

Comment: What warning/error you're getting when doing make (with verbose parameter: `-v`) if any, during the time when these patches are applied? Or nothing at all?

Comment: How the second .make is invoked? Shouldn't be included using: `includes[]`?

Comment: @kenorb The second .make file is invoked because `drush make` is recursive. When the profile is retrieved by the the stub .make file, drush will notice that it also includes a .make file and will run that too. See https://www.drupal.org/node/1006620

Comment: @kenorb I think I tried verbose output and didn't notice any errors.

Comment: Can you share the filenames of your `.make` files, I think this is important. See: [Managing Drush make files for an installation profile](https://www.drupal.org/node/1476014). So double check that your .make file names are correct.

Comment: @kernob I don't see anything on that page that suggests that the .make file names have any bearing on things. In fact, it only points out the total opposite > _there's no magic about this filename -- "build-[distro].make" is just a convention"_

Comment: If you would publish the profile into Drupal, you probably would see similar error as [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1986838/release): `Packaging error messages No makefile for ads profile, skipping extended packaging.` which actually suggesting that it looking for some specific names. See also [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/751242#comment-2762256) which saying that the file should be `drupal-org.make`. This is used for packaging script, but I'm not sure if this is relevant during the make, you can try if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the core patch in the core stub makefile. Here is mine straight out of [buildkit](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/buildkit/tree/drupal-org-core.make).

```
api = 2
core = 7.x

projects[drupal][type] = core
projects[drupal][version] = "7.39"

; Use vocabulary machine name for permissions
; http://drupal.org/node/995156
projects[drupal][patch][995156] = http://drupal.org/files/issues/995156-5_portable_taxonomy_permissions.patch

projects[example][type] = profile
projects[example][download][type] = git
projects[example][download][url] = git@github.com:Laudanum/example.git
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had tried moving the patch to the sub .make file but still wasn't having any luck. It turns out that the trick is to specify which version of core you want to download. I was just specifying "drupal" which will just grab the latest stable version of Drupal 7. Your stub file specified "7.39" and in doing so the patch then gets applied.